# Cytoscape Edges Coordinates

Tags: cytoscape.js

I'm having problems getting edges coordinates ( x, y).
Is there any solution?

```
cy.on('tap', function(e) {
    if (e.cyTarget === cy) {
        ...
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `midpoint` method to get model position coordinates of edges:

```js
cy.on('tap', function(e){
    // Checking if the target is not the background and if it is an edge
    if(typeof e.cyTarget.isEdge !== 'undefined' && e.cyTarget.isEdge()) {
        // Logging its position
        console.log(e.cyTarget.midpoint());
    }
});
```

More information on `midpoint` method can be found [here](http://js.cytoscape.org/#edge.midpoint).

Comment: Edited the answer because the first version had the wrong method.